# Javascript Popup for Mixpanel User Identification

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mixpanel

I'm working on integrating Mixpanel Analytics into my blog, http://andrewaustin.me. I'm trying to identify users so I can track their path through the site.

I want to make a panel pop up over my webpage asking for the user's name, then calling mixpanel.alias('name_that_was_just_inputted');

There would be a close button, and the panel would close if clicked outside of the panel. That would call mixpanel.track("userpanel_close")

How would I go about doing this? I am inexperienced at Javascript. Thanks!

EDIT: Of course, the panel would have to call mixpanel.register to place a cookie saying the user has already input their details, and check for the cookie so the panel doesn't appear every time someone loads a new page or returns to my site.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(localStorage.userEdits==null)
var username=prompt("Enter your name");
if(username!=null){
localStorage.userEdits=username;
//do what you want
}
}else{
alert("You are already registered as "+localStorage.userEdits);
}
```

This is the most simplest solution.